# How to search string for keyword and display string without keyword in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, keyword, interpreter

I'm currently developing my own programming language with C# and I am having a problem trying to do something. I have the part figured out where I need to read the code and store it in a string. But, my problem is, I'm trying to have it where I search for a keyword and display that line without the keyword.
For example i would like to work like this:

- Code: Print Hello
- Display: Hello

I'm having trouble getting that to work in C#.
My existing code:

```
public void Run()
    {
        string uriPath;
        uriPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
        string path = new Uri(uriPath).LocalPath;
        NBasicInfo info = new NBasicInfo();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Run Project");
        Console.WriteLine("=======================================");
        Console.WriteLine("Files to open: ");
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path + @"\NDOS\Programs\NBasic");
        for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; ++i)
        {
            string _path = filePaths[i];
            Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_path));
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
         Console.Write("Project Name (Name before .nbasic) (Do not include .nbasic): ");
         string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
         try
         {
            StreamReader contentCode = new StreamReader(path + @"\NDOS\Programs\NBasic\" + fileName + ".nbasic");
            string codeContent = contentCode.ReadToEnd();
            contentCode.Close();
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NBasicInfo));
            FileStream read = new FileStream(path + @"\NDOS\Programs\NBasic\" + fileName + ".xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            NBasicInfo info2 = (NBasicInfo)xs.Deserialize(read);
            info2.pname = info2.ProjectName;
            info2.aname = info2.ApplicationName;
            info2.dname = info2.DeveloperName;
            read.Close();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Running " + info2.aname + "...");
            Console.WriteLine("===================================================================");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
            Console.ReadKey();
         }
         catch
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Error running code. Please check code and correct any mistakes.");
         }
    }
```

What i need is the code that will search for the keyword (in this case 'print') and display the words after that.

- Thank you, Nicholas

Comment: where are the commands.

Comment: The command i would like working write now is just "print". So when i write print hello, the program would interpret it and display hello. **i need to learn how to write the interpreter in c#**

Comment: Where is the c# code that handles NBasic commands?

Comment: That's my problem, there isn't as i don't know how to do that

Comment: So far i have the RUN() void which reads the file, but i don't know how to interpret the file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't write code for you

Comment: so you are writing a language and don't know how to write a language?  well perhaps you should learn about lexers and parsers and perhaps have a look at antlr instead of rolling your own

Comment: We cant offer any advice becasuse we dont know what your data looks like. Where are the commands in your program (you say you are reading them), how are they stored,.....

Comment: I'm a beginner programmer try to figure out how to do things. I researched a bunch on this topic and couldn't find an answers solving my problem. i am not asking you to write code for me, i am asking for advice or a hint on the basis of what i need to do. I know how to use the keyword function already. I'm asking on help on removing the keyword from the string when writing the line to the console.

Comment: @pm100 if you look at the code above, a have a StreamReader that reads the context of the file and stores it in a string. The file that contains the code is a regular text file with the text: PRINT hello world

Comment: @Nick First get very familiar with string operations in general, then file operations. Write simple code that breaks up strings in various ways. Then read about parsing, lexers, etc. if you're trying to write an interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are developing a new programming language... here is a **super ultra basic** example (for better understanding the constraints required in such a task ) to do it more maintainable and save all the nested if steatments as  @Keith Nicholas mentioned:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintKeyWords.CheckForKeyWord("print hello world!!!");
        PrintKeyWords.CheckForKeyWord("specialPrint hello world!!!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

delegate void ExecuteMethod();
public static class PrintKeyWords
{

    private static string Command { get; set; }
    public static void CheckForKeyWord(string cmd)
    {

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ExecuteMethod> keyword in KeyWordsDict)
        {
            if (cmd.StartsWith(keyword.Key))
            {
                Command = cmd;
                KeyWordsDict[keyword.Key].Invoke();
                return;
            }
        }
            Console.WriteLine("your command is not recognized as an internal or exter
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, ExecuteMethod> _KeyWordsDict;
    private static Dictionary<string, ExecuteMethod> KeyWordsDict
    {
        get
        {
            if (_KeyWordsDict == null)
            {
                _KeyWordsDict = new Dictionary<string, ExecuteMethod>();
                _KeyWordsDict.Add("print", Print);
                _KeyWordsDict.Add("specialPrint", SpecialPrint);
                return _KeyWordsDict;
            }

            else
            {
                return _KeyWordsDict;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Command.Replace("print", ""));
    }

    private static void SpecialPrint()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Command.Replace("specialPrint", "") + "*****************");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at this and try implementing it into my program.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a simple answer

```
if(command.StartsWith("Print"))
{
  Console.WriteLine(command.Substring(6));
}
```

but thats not really a worldclass language interpreter

Comment: Thank you for this. I only needed a sample of what it would look like and i could figure out the rest. I will test this out now and let you know if i have any problems. Thank you again

Comment: @pm100 not sure if you helped him or sent him on the way of some horrendously large nested if statements and a whole lot of string munging :)

Comment: Now this did work, but only with one line. But, if i have multiple lines how would i have it move to the next line and do it again? Would i have to use a goto statement or something different?

Comment: @keith lol maybe, we will have to see where this will take us

Comment: @Nick - sigh. First things first. Learn how to read a text file into and array of lines, then just print each line. Baby steps.

Comment: @pm100 i can do that but i want to print each line without the print

Comment: if you want to write a real interprter you need to read each line and tokenize it. HAve a base class of command with derived class for each command type, each command type has its own args. Then run over the 'program' doing .Exec on each command in turn. HAve fun

Comment: I'll try and figure this out, Thanks!

Comment: By the way i'm trying to implement this for my new operating system! Check it out: [NDOS](http://nickvisiondos.weebly.com/)

Comment: well, gonna be a good learning experience.